# How do I make a rectangle with user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rectangles

I need to make a square with 2 pieces of user input: `n` and `m`. The rectangle has to be `n * m` and made out of `"*"`. I can make the square if I say for example `n = (5)` and `m = (7)`, when I add make `m` and `n` user input it prints `n` instead of a rectangle made of `"*"`... This is what I have so far, what am I doing wrong?

```
n = int(input(3))
m = int(input(4))
for i in range(n):
    print ('*' * m)
```

The expected output is:

```
****
****
****
```

Edit:
Ok, I think my problem is that I don't know how to correctly enter input, can anyone help me on that?
Second Edit:
Alright, thanks everybody for helping! I found out how it works, I didn't enter actual input after running the program. Thanks again!

Comment: What do you expect `int(input(3))` to do?

Comment: you need two `for`: outer for the rows and inner for the columns on each row.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. What is the expected output ? can you post an example ?

Comment: Your code is just waiting for you to type a value to assign to `n`; the `3` is a prompt, not the value of `n`.

Comment: "stackoverflow won't let me post an example..." sure it does. After all, it's just plain text output, right? Format it as 'code'.

Comment: I expect an output of 3 stars (*) vertically

Comment: You have to enter a value for `n` and `m` so if you want a square of 4 across and 4 down, then type 4 ENTER and then 4 ENTER.

Comment: Just to be clear: when I only give n and m a value it works. The problem happens when I add the input part. I have to hand it in without value's (they will be determined when it is checked) will it work if I hand it in with everything but without me giving n and m a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a rectangle.

```
n = int(input("First number "))
m = int(input("Second number "))
star = "*"
for i in range(n):
    print(star*m)
```

Example:

```
First number 4
Second number 8
********
********
********
********
```

Comment: this code is exactly the same as the one of the OP.

Comment: When I do exactly what you suggest, it prints: 4. When I delete: int(input() and only have n = (4) and m = (8) it does work...

Comment: Just the number 4?

Comment: @Stubbs There's nothing wrong with the OP's code; all you've done is changed the prompt displayed by `input`, which is what led to the OP's confusion.

Comment: Yeah there is nothing wrong, but the inputs shouldn't have an int as a prompt. Sorry for the confusion, I thought my answer made it clearer.

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't know how to correctly enter input... how do I do that?

Comment: How are you currently running the code? For example the way I have done it is so it will print out "First number" then you type the number you want and press enter, then it will do the same for "Second number".

Comment: @Stubbs Yeah, I forgot to do exactly what you said. Thank you!